# Several Drivers unavailable after dual boot with Windows 7/Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers

I just dual booted my system 76 laptop with Windows 7 x64 and Ubuntu 14.04. After a successful installation though, Windows 7 is not detecting several drivers including my WiFi and Ethernet. Can anyone advise what other ways I can have Windows find the driver software as I tried uninstalling the Hardware and re-installing it and still nothing.

The error code I get is: "The drivers for this devise are not installed. (Code 28)"

Comment: Sorry x64 is what I have

Comment: Thanks for the help ppl smh. I dont know why this question is being down voted in the first place!

Comment: Can someone please help me, I looked up resources online and could not find anything?!

Comment: If you are unable to get your wireless working then I would suggest you get your Ethernet working first. Log on to your Ubuntu (that should find your Ethernet) and go online to download the Windows 7 64-Bit drivers for your Ethernet adapter - to get your Ethernet adapter from Linux (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-ethernet-adapter-ubuntu-linux/). Once you've got these on a USB stick go to Windows, install, update your drivers from Windows Update etc.

Comment: Can you post this as your answer, as that seemed to help

Comment: I've had this: I solved it by shutting down and powering off completely, ie remove the power lead (and battery if a laptop), before booting the other system.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually downloaded the driver software in another computer and installed it via USB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are unable to connect your Windows 7 to any network (WiFi or Ethernet) you will need to obtain the drivers using an alternative method. Luckily, you have Ubuntu installed in a dual-boot configuration.

If your Ubuntu has Internet connectivity I would recommend that you:

1. Download the Windows Ethernet (or WiFi) drivers for your laptop using Ubuntu.
2. Use a memory stick to save the driver installation files
3. Boot to Windows
4. Install the network drivers
5. Connect to your network and ensure Internet connectivity
6. Run Windows Update to let it try to download drivers for your other devices.

If Windows Update cannot install drivers automatically then you will need to use the manufacturer media or download from their website.

For future readers: It is always useful to make a CD containing all the most important driver installation files for such devices as Ethernet and WiFi cards on your computer!